# Google Pay in Android paymentsClient.isReadyToPay back false

Tags: android

I use the official dome, the return is also false
Google Pay account  is  xiang0pan@gmail.com
phone model  is  redmi k30 pro
Google play is 22.3.13

```
Task<Boolean> task = paymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request);
        task.addOnCompleteListener(mActivity,
                new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (task.getResult()) {
                                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            } else {
                                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                        } else {
                            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Log.w("isReadyToPay failed", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
```